# Cannot read property 'items' of null for adding new items to a custom name list

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I learning how to create a to-do list web app. I encounter some problems when I want to add some new items into custom list, my console log this warnings: Cannot read property 'items' of null.

[image]

Another problem is, when I enter a new custom list after /, the new custom list should be shown as a title on the current page (the violet part), but it never show at all.

[image]

I do read some Q&A which is related to this course. Mostly the answer is they have extra space in *value="<%= listTitle %>"*, which is the code inside ejs file. (I'll show my code later)

My code shown as below, as you can see there are not any extra space in *value="<%= listTitle %>"*. So I literally cannot figure out what is the problem.

```
<%- include("header") -%>

<div class="box" id="heading">
  <h1><%= listTitle %></h1>
</div>

<div class="box">



<% newListItems.forEach(function(item) { %>
<form action="/delete" method="post">
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%=item._id%>" onChange="this.form.submit( )">
    <p><%=item.name%></p>
  </div>
</form>
<% }) %>


<form class="item" action="/" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="New Item" autocomplete="off">
  <button type="submit" name="list" value="<%= listTitle %>">+</button>
</form>
</div>

<%- include("footer") -%>
```

**And this is my js file:**

```
//jshint esversion:6

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");


const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

//create & connect database
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost: 27017/todolistDB", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

//create mongoose schema
const itemsSchema = {
  name: String
};

//create model
const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemsSchema);

//create documents & put them into array
const item1 = new Item({
  name: "Welcome to your todolist!",
});

const item2 = new Item({
  name: "Hit the + button to add a new item.",
});

const item3 = new Item({
  name: "<-- Hit this to delete an item.",
});

const defaultItems = [item1, item2, item3];

//create a new schema for custon name list
const listSchema = {
  name: String,
  items: [itemsSchema]
};

//create a new model for custon name list
const List = mongoose.model("List", listSchema);


app.get("/", function(req, res) {

  Item.find({}, function(err, foundItems) {

    if (foundItems.length === 0) {
      Item.insertMany(defaultItems, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log("Successfully saved default iems to Database");
        }
      });
      res.redirect("/");
    } else {
      res.render("list", {listTitle: "Today", newListItems: foundItems});
    }
  });
});

app.get("/:customListName", function(req, res) {
  const customListName = req.params.CustomListName;

  List.findOne({name: customListName}, function(err, foundList) {
    if (!err) {
      if (!foundList) {
        //Create a new list
        const list = new List({
          name: customListName,
          items: defaultItems
        });

        list.save();
        res.redirect("/" + customListName);
      } else {
        //Show an existing list
        res.render("list", {listTitle: foundList.name, newListItems: foundList.items});
      }
    }
  });
});

app.post("/", function(req, res) {

  const itemName = req.body.newItem;
  const listName = req.body.list;

  const item = new Item({
    name: itemName
  });

  if (listName === "Today") {
    item.save();
    res.redirect("/");
  } else {
    List.findOne({name: listName}, function(err, foundList) {
      foundList.items.push(item);

      foundList.save();
      res.redirect("/" + listName);
    });
  }
});

app.post("/delete", function(req, res) {
  const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox; //.checkbox is from ejs list

  Item.findByIdAndRemove(checkedItemId, function(err) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log("Successfully deleted checked item!");
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  });
});

app.get("/about", function(req, res) {
  res.render("about");
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Hope that anyone can help out with my questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in the post handler. First of all, `foundList` is coming empty, and you are checking `items` on it which throws an error. Check why it is coming empty. Secondly, `foundList.save()` won't work, you need to create an instance for this and then call save method on it.

Check the List collection data why it is not saving anything. When you get the list follow the above steps.

```
app.post("/", function(req, res) {

  const itemName = req.body.newItem;
  const listName = req.body.list;

  const item = new Item({
    name: itemName
  });

  if (listName === "Today") {
    item.save();
    res.redirect("/");
  } else {
    // make sure listName is correct
    List.findOne({name: listName}, function(err, foundList) {
      foundList.items.push(item);   --> Issue is here
      foundList.save(); 
      res.redirect("/" + listName);
    });
  }
});
```

I am posting this answer as I can't explain these things in the comments.

Comment: Hi Chikara, thanks for your reply & suggestion. I log my code which might have wrong, then I discover it's only a typo occur in the part of :/customNameList.